# Authorization Expiration message from ArcGIS for Desktop after much less than expected one year?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, license

I have used ArcGIS (student edition with license) less than a year (in fact I only used it a month and a half) and I got an Authorization Expiration message.I did not obtain the code from the website, I just got it from my instructor for my summer class.

What should I do?
[image: Authorization Expiration message]

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify whether this is the mechanism you used to obtain that license: http://www.esri.com/industries/apps/education/offers/promo/index.cfm but in any event I think you should contact whoever provided you with that license which I suspect would be Esri, one of its distributors or a tertiary institution.

Comment: Is is the core software or is it an extension? Many people select to evaluate extensions when they install the software. The evaluation period is not very long and this could be your warning, could you include a screenshot of the warning?

Answer (score 1):

The software is reporting that it has expired, so I think you will need to trace the date on which it was first activated, if you wish to demonstrate that it has expired prematurely.

Since it was your instructor who provided you with the authorization code, it is that person who would appear to be the next link to try and trace the date of first activation.

---

While I was writing the above you posted a screenshot that indicates that the license code which is going to time out is `Video`.  This is not one with which I am familiar, but I am thinking it may be the [ArcGIS Full Motion Video Add-In](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/09/28/the-arcgis-full-motion-video-add-in-updated-with-tutorial-exercises/).  If you are not using that, and just want to disable/suppress the license expiration message, then follow the instructions in [HowTo:  Disable timeout warning for expired extensions](http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/17891).